# Google analytics Site search is not working as expected

Tags: search, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I just started using Google analytics for my website. I found that, enabling site search for a site is very easy as mentioned below,

[image]

But my site doesn't have the search term in the query string, instead it is part of the url as mentioned below,

```
https://mydomian.net/search#q=boxtest18
```

for some internal reason i cannot modify the code to append search term as  querystring to url.

[This](https://www.digishuffle.com/blogs/internal-site-search-google-analytics/) article explained how to configure site search in GA, if Site Search Term Is Present in the URL: NOT As Query Parameter (Single Term).

When i tried, it doesn't seem working.

Below is my filter configuration.

[image]

What i'm doing wrong here?

Can i use the filter for this kind of url?

Is my regular expression correct?

Help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into Google analytics and Google tag manager i found the solution. Solution was very easy in my case.

For every search, search term was updating in the url fragment. In the below case, i searched for `boxtest18` and url updated like below.

https://mydomian.net/search#q=boxtest18

For this, i had crerated a Tag in Google tag manager and triggered it on history change event. That resovled my problem.

Here are the steps.

1. In google tag manager i have added new tag and filled highlighted info.
   [image]
2. Fragment value is a variable which i created.
   [image]
3. For the new tag i have created the triggering event as shown below.
   [image]

And make sure you have the tracking code script  and Google tag manager script in your web page. That's it. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

As Michele mentioned you may append the hash when the query is visible in url hash;

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {
  'page_path': location.pathname + location.hash
});
```

though if you are using requests (ajax or any restful api) you should manually trigger a page view as a virtual page.

```
  pagePath = location.pathname
  gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {page_path: pagePath + '?gender=' + request.gender });

  // or if using analytics.js
  ga('send', 'pageview', pagePath + '?gender=' + request.gender);
```

> For more info, here is the help section for sending posts
>   https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en#Post

---

### Pageview Request Object

You may use these to manually trigger a page view for a virtual page. If you are looking to use analytics.js (`ga()`) please refer to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages)

```
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'page_title' : 'homepage',
  'page_path': '/home'
});

Parameter name  Value type  Required    Description
page_title      string      No          The page's title.
page_location   string      No          The page's URL.
page_path       string      No          The path portion of location. This value 
                                            must start with a slash (/) character.
```

> For more info, here is the official documentation
>   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages

---

### Event Request Object

*I am adding this section for completeness*

You may use these to trigger a tracking event. If you are looking to use analytics.js (`ga()`) please refer to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

**action** is the string that will appear as the event action in Google Analytics Event reports.

**category** is the string that will appear as the event category.

**label** *(optional)* is the string that will appear as the event label.

**value** *(optional)* is a non-negative integer that will appear as the event value.

> For more info, here is the official documentation
>   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me what is request object? and what it contains?

Comment: Hey @PaRsH I have added the request objects that are required for pageviews and events. Just to clarify, you should still be using the gtag or analytics.js methods to do this. but you will be triggering those (logically) while you handle your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Analytics the **URL** paths that are passed to GA with your Pageview hits **are stripped** of these **fragments**.

You can update the data before sending it to Analytics (track pageviews).

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {
  'page_path': location.pathname + location.hash
});
```

Or you can use Google Tag Manager to get the fragment, more info here: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-url-fragments-as-pageviews/

Then you can handle it as you like or replace the `#` to the `?` with a filter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did worked partially. But ajax search is not seems to be working. Any help here?

Comment: Ajax Search is a topic that goes beyond the context of Analytics, you should open a new dedicated thread with the appropriate tags, eg: javascript. If you solved the current question with suggest in my answer mark it as solved, pls.